# Rails view URL to another website

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, url

In my view I display a url to another website like so:

```
 <a href="url"><%= @article.url %></a>
```

However, when I click it, my website crashes(it probably interprets it as a url to another page within the website).

How can I change this code such that the url takes me to another website?

Comment: Does your url include protocol? e.g. `http://`

Comment: If it doesn't, Rails will interpret as internal url

Comment: check out these [ActionViews Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `link_to` [Action View Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) like so:

```
<%= link_to "External Link", @article.url %>
```

Assuming `@article.url` return the appropriate url

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the rails `ActionView::Helpers` to show urls.

```
<%= link_to "Visit Other Site", @article.url %>
```

will compile to

```
<a href="http://www.rubyonrails.org/">Visit Other Site</a>
```

Link to the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `link_to` for this. And even  you can pass extra stuff like class name of styles with it easily . Please do check Rails Guides .

```
<%=  link_to "Articles", articles_path, id: "news", class: "article" %>
```